# Re-weighted regularized linear least squares for integer programming?

Tags: reference-request, optimization, soft-question, least-squares, mixed-integer-programming

Say I have a vector of integers ${\bf a} = [a_1,\cdots,a_N]^T$ and an optimizations problem I would like to find a solution (or approximation) in this set.

Assume for every number, a probability distribution ${\bf p} = [p_1,p_2,\cdots,p_N]^T$, so that $$\sum_{k=1}^{N} p_k = {\bf 1}^T{\bf p} = 1$$

Then we can calculate expectation:

$$E[{\bf a}] = \sum_{k=1}^{N}p_ka_k = {\bf a}^T{\bf p}$$

Now we can enforce the first one with a squares cost term: $$\|{\bf 1}^T{\bf p}-1\|_2^2$$

We can use the second one to steer the solution towards the correct mean value:

$$\|{\bf a}^T{\bf p}-\mu\|_2^2$$

Now what remains is some kind of variance or entropy minimization. Ideally we want a solution that tells us with $100\%$ certainty exactly what each integer variable should be, this corresponds to variance $0$ and entropy $0$.

**Own approach:**

Re-weighted Tikhonov regularization $${\bf \Lambda }_{n}= \text{diag}( f({\bf v}_{n-1}) )$$

Where $f$ is some function which maps $1$ to small costs and $0$ to large costs (and negative numbers to even larger costs).

---

How feasible is this approach?

Which other methods can be used?

Is there some kind of guarantee of convergence?

Comment: Is $\mathbf{a}$ fixed, and you are optimizing over $\mathbf{p}$ only?

Comment: @RobPratt Initially, yes. It is surely interesting to allow also $\bf a$ to change, but that would be a bit too much for one question, I suppose.

Comment: Also, should $a_0$ instead be $a_1$? If $\mu$ is between $\min_k a_k$ and $\max_k a_k$, you can find a $\mathbf{p}$ via linear programming, with your two linear constraints and any objective function.

Comment: @RobPratt yep a linear optimization with constraints solver could work for this purpose. However I am trying to avoid constraints to be able to fit everything into the same unconstrained least squares framework. Trying to turn constraints into possibly (iteratively reweighted) cost functions for this purpose.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you're trying to enforce. Is is only sum to 1 and mean of $ \boldsymbol{a} $ or something additional?

Comment: @Royi In the end I want to be able to express and solve all (of reasonably small dimensionality) integer minimization problems on a certain set by using only (reweighted) regularized linear least squares. Any method to enforce a monomodal distribution could help in that endeavour, but I am not sure if it will be enough.

Comment: The way the question is described I don't understand how one should create the problem itself. We have the vector $ \boldsymbol{p} $ could you list the constraints besides its sum to be $ 1 $ and and the mean?

Comment: @Royi Yes the problem here is how to construct the problem so that it can solve a problem expressed in integer programs. We want to find optimal integer solutions, possibly together with linear constraints.

Comment: I don't see the integer here as $ \boldsymbol{p} $ by definition has numbers which are less or equal to 1. Again, The constraints in the question aren't clear. Please try to edit the question to make it clearer.

Comment: @Royi it is literally in the first line of the question. $\bf a$ is a vector of integers. $\bf p$ is a probability distribution. We want to solve for this distribution and encourage it to become as deterministic as we can with regularization (or maybe other methods).

Comment: But if the optimization is over $ \boldsymbol{p} $ only (See your remark) who cares about $ \boldsymbol{a} $?